# Cyrus IMAP mailbox replication. Is it encrypted over the WAN?

Tags: imap, cyrus

Servers are both Debian 9.  According to [Debian package search](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=cyrus-imapd) they are version 2.5.10.

I need to find out if replication as described here [Cyrus Documentation: Replication](https://www.cyrusimap.org/2.5/imap/admin/sop/replication.html) is encrypted over the WAN.

I know it can be with version 3+, as the replication protocol has been changed to use IMAP itself, which can be over SSL/TLS.  That would however require a custom build on Debian.

I need to decide if I need to set up an IPSEC tunnel before I deploy it? or do I make a custom build?

Comment: It seems very unlikely, as there isn't any configuration option for encryption in the old csync protocol.

Comment: That's what I feared.  The master is in a data-centre 650 miles away.  The slave is here at home.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, if you could please suggest that I use an IPSEC tunnel, I'll mark your question correct and explain fully how I did it, and what the pitfalls are.  Thank you for being a good moderator.

Comment: If you solved the problem yourself, you can and should [answer your own question](/help/self-answer).

Comment: OK, thanks @MichaelHampton, I'll post up some diagrams tomorrow.  It relates to another question too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution, was to deploy StrongSwan, an IPSEC tunnel, not wanting to have to spend much time looking at source code of Cyrus.

There is a description here:  [Debian 9 dummy network adapter - works on Local but not Remote?](https://serverfault.com/questions/935152/debian-9-dummy-network-adapter-works-on-local-but-not-remote)

There is a diagram too.  See my answer on that thread for corrections to it.  i.e. do not use the dummy network interface.  It is unreliable.